# Type error: Argument 1 passed to: hasPermission() must be an instance of: Permission string given

Tags: php, laravel

tô preso num erro aqui no Laravel e não entendi porque ele esta ocorrendo, a mensagem em si eu entendi, que eu estou passando como parâmetro para a função um valor que é string quando devia ser uma instância de minha model, mas antes funcionava e não entendi porque esta ocorrendo esse erro agora, segue os arquivos:

**AuthServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    $permissions = Permission::with('roles')->get();

    foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
        Gate::define($permission->name, function($user) use ($permission) {
            return $user->hasPermission($permission->name);
        });
    }
}
```

A model: **User.php**

```
/**
 * @param \Api\Users\Models\Permission $permission
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function hasPermission(Permission $permission)
{
    return $this->hasAnyRoles($permission->roles);
}

/**
 * @param $roles
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function hasAnyRoles($roles)
{
    if(is_array($roles) || is_object($roles) ) {
        return !! $roles->intersect($this->roles)->count();
    }

    return $this->roles->contains('name', $roles);
}
```

eis o erro que ocorre:

> "Type error: Argument 1 passed to Api\Users\Models\User::hasPermission() must be an instance of Api\Acl\Models\Permission, string given, called in C:\wamp\www\restfulapi_test\infrastructure\Providers\AuthServiceProvider.php on line 34"

Comment: Tente só trocar o $permission->name  pelo objeto $permission.

Comment: Deveria ser `$this->hasAnyRoles($permission);` o correto, não é?

Comment: não tenho certeza, mas vou fazer o teste

Comment: @arllondias era isso mesmo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `hasAnyRoles` espera no primeiro argumento precisa ser um objeto do tipo `Api\Acl\Models\Permission`, no caso você passou o `$permission->roles` que provavelmente contém outro tipo de objeto ou valor:

```
public function hasPermission(Permission $permission)
{
    return $this->hasAnyRoles($permission->roles);
}
```

Por isto a mensagem de erro:

> Argument 1 passed to Api\Users\Models\User::hasPermission() must be an instance of Api\Acl\Models\Permission

Traduzida seria:

> O primeiro argumento passado para Api\Users\Models\User::hasPermission() precisa ser uma instancia de Api\Acl\Models\Permission

Como no `hasPermission(Permission $permission)` você já recebe o objeto então provavelmente tenha que fazer isto:

```
public function hasPermission(Permission $permission)
{
    return $this->hasAnyRoles($permission);
}
```